# laravel mail attach() method returns error about null argument

Tags: php, laravel, email, amazon-ses, laravel-mail

---

Hello, I'm making a mail service in laravel, that supports attachment upload, when the user send me the file, I store it in a Amazon S3 driver for further attachment.
Here's my Mail class witch I send the mail object with the copies of email and attachments.

```
<?php

namespace App\Mail;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;
    use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;

   class Mail extends Mailable
   {
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public $email;
    public $attachments;
    public $copies;

    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($email, $copies = [], $attachments = [])
    {
        $this->email = $email;
        $this->copies = $copies;
        $this->attachments = $attachments;
    }

    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {
        $m = $this->from($this->email->sender->email, $this->email->sender->name)
            ->replyTo($this->email->sender->email, $this->email->sender->name)
            ->subject($this->email->subject);

        foreach ($this->copies as $copy) {
            if ($copy->type == 'CC') {
                $m->cc($copy->destiny->email);
            } else {
                $m->bcc($copy->destiny->email);
            }
        }

        if (!empty($this->attachments)) {
            foreach ($this->attachments as $attachment) {
                $attachmentParameters = [
                    "as" => $attachment->name,
                    "mime" => $attachment->mime
                ];

                $m->attach(Storage::disk('s3Attachments')->url($attachment->path), $attachmentParameters);
            }
        }

        return $m->view('emails.text-plain');
    }
}
```

I've already used the `dd(Storage::disk('s3Attachments')->url($attachment->path))` and confirmed that it is a string with the full path of the file like the documentation asks.

> To add attachments to an email, use the attach method within the
>   mailable class' build method. The attach method accepts the full path
>   to the file as its first argument:

Then When I run the code, it brings this error:

```
[2018-05-05 20:58:52] testing.ERROR: Type error: Argument 2 passed to Illuminate\Mail\Message::attach() must be of the type array, null given, called in /home/lefel/Sites/happymail/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Mail/Mailable.php on line 311
```

I've tried using attach(), with just one argument:

```
$m->attach(Storage::disk('s3Attachments')->url($attachment->path));
```

But Same Error, I'm Using Laravel 5.5 with Amazon SES Driver, and already confirmed that I installed the following dependencies in my package.json:

```
composer require guzzlehttp/guzzle
"aws/aws-sdk-php": "~3.0"
```

I've searched the web and didn't find the solution, I need Help Please.

Regards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have just faced the exact same issue.
The problem is that you override the $attachments property.

Use another name for this variable and it will work!